# HTML Canvas morphing & moving over a transparent background

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, overlay, transparency

I saw a very interesting canvas technique on the site http://capitolcouture.pn/ when clicking on Issue 1. This flower/circle Effect.

I'm quite familiar with the canvas element drawing diagrams and so on, but I'm not able to examine how the transparent circle is created and put over the second canvas with text.

**EDIT**

Because of the tip, that people don't follow links from stackoverflow beginners I try to explain the effect.

1. You have 2 canvas elements.
2. One is lying on top of the other.
3. The canvas lying below the first one contains some text.
4. If one hovers over the top canvas, a certain radius around the mousepointer gets transparent cleared on the second canvas.
5. On this mouse hover, the first canvas spawns graphics corresponding to the second ones text letters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: People are hesitant to follow links on questions by first-time posters.

Comment: Thats a fancy effect, it would be a bit of a hefty write up to describe how they did it [here is a pen with some code that should help](http://codepen.io/soulwire/pen/Ffvlo) main difference is using images rather than dots.